# SharePoint document library view

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, view

I want to create a list view filtering by [ Me ] 
, and the one who has full control can see everything ?
possible ?

THNX

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would get the user with Full Control (or the site admins), to create themselves a **private** view, as opposed to a **public** one. Within the public view, items will be filtered using the **[ME]** attribute, whereas you can then specify the parameters of the private/personal view you have created. Additionally, within the general permission levels of all users, you may want to uncheck the "Manage Lists" option, this will allow the user to create a **public** view.